# Can I toggle fringe-mode when entering / exiting edebug?

Tags: edebug, fringe-mode

Paraphrasing [a question I previously asked on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/603441/can-i-toggle-fringe-mode-when-entering-exiting-emacs-edebug/639624) because, IMO, the answer found there does not resolve the issue.

### Question

For the most part I prefer to disable Emacs' fringe. (I customize `fringe-mode` to `0` a/k/a `no-fringes`)  But I like to have the left fringe active when debugging elisp code (for the little fringe arrow pointing to the active line).

How can I configure Emacs to switch to `fringe-mode` of `(nil . 0)` a/k/a `left-only` when entering edebug and restore the previous `fringe-mode` when exiting?

### Update

Since Emacs 24.3 is the latest stable release as of this writing, I have a preference for solutions that work there.  Since Emacs 24.4 is available, in feature-freeze, and actively in use by several users of this site, I'm accepting that answer.

Comment: I can confirm that the suggested code works perfectly for me. You might want to verify the behavior on your side with `emacs -q`

Comment: Even the `message` code?  I've tried `emacs -Q` + eval either one, or both, in the \*scratch\* buffer, call a command I'd previously instrumented with `C-u C-M-x`.  I have yet to see any joy.

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by "works perfectly"?

Comment: If "***`edebug-mode-hook` is never run***", then clearly you cannot say that the function added to that hook does not work. *Suggestion:* Figure out why it does not run - that's your first step.

Comment: Sorry to be explicit, but I'm calling B.S. that `edebug-mode-hook` exists in Emacs.  I cannot find it documented anywhere, I see no reason to believe that the code in edebug.el creates it, and all suggested code that I write fails to use it the way one would expect.  This is all true when I start from `emacs -Q`.
*breathe*
It may be my ignorance of the internals of edebug.  When I go: `emacs -Q`, instrument a command with `C-u C-M-x`, call the command, then go `C-h v edebug-mode-hook RET` I am taken to the (sparse) documentation of the `edebug-eval-mode-hook`.  What am I missing?

Comment: To be clear: I'm not claiming that the code given above fails to compile, or that the functions in the lambda forms are somehow broken.  I'm claiming that the call to `add-hook` creates a hook symbol that never existed before, and I see no reason to expect edebug to ever consult that symbol again.

Comment: Try loading the edebug library `M-x load-library` before searching for `edebug-mode-hook`. It is a mode hook and does not have to be explicitly defined.

Comment: *People the discrepancy probably comes from emacs versions.* In
 **Emacs 24.3**, `edebug-mode` is a standard function, and
 `edebug-mode-hook` really isn’t used *nor* defined. In **Emacs 24.4**,
 `edebug-mode` is defined through `define-minor-mode`, so
 `edebug-mode-hook` is defined *and* used.

Comment: @Malabarba, thank you!  And thanks to everybody for helping me debug this.  *facepalm*  If any participant in this helpful thread would like to write that up as an answer, I'll accept it.  I'm not sure how content I am with "upgrade to the dev version of Emacs" but it *is* a valid answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re using **Emacs 24.4**, the code you’ve posted (which I’m repeating below) should be enough.

```
(add-hook 'edebug-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set-fringe-mode
             (set (make-local-variable 'fringe-mode)
                  (if edebug-mode '(nil . 0) 0)))))
```

I’m positing this as answer for completeness, I understand it doesn’t
statisfy your needs. I tried to look a bit into `edebug`’s source
code, to find a function I could advise and get a similar effect, but
failed.

#### On Emacs 24.4

Emacs 24.4 has been in feature freeze for a while now and is unlikely
to change very much until release. Plenty of people are using it daily, and I haven’t run into any problems whatsoever.
I won’t go into how to install it, as that’s another question
entirely.